# How would one go about pricing a FX future?

Tags: options, fx, futures, derivatives, swaps

What model/equations would I require to calculate the price for a foreign exchange future? This is in an attempt to mitigate foreign exchange risk. Also, how could one measure a business's exposure to FX risk?

Comment: For FX future pricing there is the entire literature related to carry model. Regarding measuring the FX exposure, first of all you should specify whether you refer to transaction, economic or translation exposure. Afterwards, expected cashflows are a first measure. Check this out https://www.bauer.uh.edu/rsusmel/4386/10.02%20(ch%2010).pdf